# When the null hypothesis is interchanged with the alternative for Binomial random variables.

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let $X_i\sim Binomial(n,p)$. Consider the following hypotheses
\begin{equation}
(a): H_0: p = p_0 \quad \mbox{versus}\quad H_1: p = p_1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(b): H_0: p = p_1 \quad \mbox{versus}\quad H_1: p = p_0
\end{equation}

If $(a)$ is rejected, what can be said about $(b)$? Is there any relation between these to hypotheses in terms of critical region?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of significance of the test. If the level of significance $\alpha_0=P(\text{reject $H_0$}|H_0)$ is small so that the rejection region has no overlap, then rejection of the hypothesis in *(a)* will necessarily mean that the hypothesis in *(b)* is not rejected, which is good. In particular, these cases are possible:

- Neither hypothesis is rejected [contradictory conclusions]
- *(a)* is rejected and *(b)* is not rejected [equivalent conclusions]
- *(b)* is rejected and *(a)* is not rejected [equivalent conclusions]

However, if the level of significance is high enough that there is overlap in the rejection region, then it is possible for both hypotheses *(a)* and *(b)* to be rejected, if say the observed data point is between the two vertical lines.

- Both hypotheses are rejected [contradictory conclusion]

[image]